# Xamarin ExoPlayer raises an exception in Java code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, stream, exoplayer

I am trying to run a simple demo using ExoPlayer on Xamarin.Android, so i installed ExoPlayer via Nuget, added the following simple code to play some audio:

```
 private SimpleExoPlayer _player;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var mediaUrl = "http://api-streaming.youscribe.com/v1/products/2919465/documents/3214936/audio/stream";
        var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mediaUrl);

        var userAgent = Util.GetUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerDemo");
        var defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
        var defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
        var extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, defaultDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
        var defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        var adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
        var defaultTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

        _player = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(this, defaultTrackSelector);
        _player.Prepare(extractorMediaSource);
        _player.PlayWhenReady = true;

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
```

When running this code i am getting the following exception:

> error: AnalyticsListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method onRenderedFirstFrame(EventTime,Surface) in AnalyticsListener
>   public class AnalyticsListenerImplementor

How do i fix that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in ExoPlayer. It's supposedly fixed in v. 2.8.1  https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin/issues/64

Comment: Well it wasn't ://, i am using the last version (2.8.1), that's why i am looking for some kind of workaround

Comment: It seems the author has already known this issue, you could keep following to it :https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin/issues/64#issuecomment-392796936

Comment: Issue solved in 2.8.3